Design of a controller with Bode plot
I have an issue with this exercise.

First of all I need to satisfy the steady-state requirement so I need that the error to output transfer function is of type 1 (i.e. it has a zero at \$s=0\$) so since \$\rm{W}_e(s)=1-\rm{W}(s)=\frac{1}{1+PG(s)}\$ then the first part of the controller is \$G_1(s)=\frac{K}{s}\$ and so
\$G(s)=G_1(s)\tilde{G}(s)\$ soI I have that
\$|e^{({ss},1)}(t)|=|\frac{\rm{W}_e(s)}{s}|_{s=0}|=|\frac{1}{sPG(s)|_{s=0}}|=|\frac{1}{K\tilde{G}(0)}|\leq0.1\$ from which \$K\$ is set either 10 or -10 depending on the stabilizable locus of the open loop system on which \$G(s)\$ acts, so I choose \$K=10\$ and \$|\tilde{G}(s)|\geq 1\$.
Then I draw the Bode Plots of \$L_1(s)=\frac{-10}{s(1-s)}\$ and I notice that \$\omega_t>\omega_t^*\$ and at \$\omega_t^*\$ the phase margin is \$m^*_\varphi=-84.29^{\circ}\$ and \$|L_1(j\omega_t^*)|=39.96 dB\$. So I need to increase the phase and decrease the magnitude by \$39.96 dB\$ at \$\omega_t^*\$. So I introduce first 2 anticipative actions of the form \$\frac{1+\tau_as}{1+\frac{\tau_as}{m_a}}\$ and then decrease the magnitude with 3 attenuative actions without decreasing too much the phase of the form \$\frac{1+\frac{\tau_is}{m_i}}{1+\tau_is}\$ (since I have a constraint given by the steady state requirement I cannot use a simple attenuative action \$K\$ with \$K \in (0,1) \$) to decrease the magnitude after the anticipative actions).
But then the Bode plot has multiple crossover frequencies and the Nyquist plot is strange. Is there another way to deal with this problem?

Why start with a pure integrator ($K/s$) instead of a proportional-integrator ($(k_p s + k_i)/s)$)?  Why "three steps of attenuation" when you already have gain as a free variable?  Why does K need to be in the range you limit yourself to?

Because of the steady state requirement which has to be satisfied: the error to output transfer function must contain one pole at s=0 in order to have a constant and non null steady state error, but maybe I could introduce two zeroes instead of one in s so that the error to ramp inputs is 0 so in module less than 0.1 and then with no constraints on the gain I could use a sufficient number of anticipative action considering the fact in our exam we have a limited number of actions from m_a=2 to m_a=16 and then lower the magnitude with a proportional action.

The limit of K was due to the fact that inequality has to be true to guarantee the steady state requirement. However this is what we did in class about the argument http://www.diag.uniroma1.it/~batti/moduli_control_systems/module_XII.pdf
